# C# Encoding on Reading HTML Page

Tags: c#, html

I am visiting a url with my program and then having the program read the resulting html.

```
    string URI = "http://www.testwebsite.com/submit?q=+mydata";
    string myParameters = "";

                    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                    {
                        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                        HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);

                    }
```

This perfectly allows me to post my data, have the website read it and then the website replies. This all works great!

HOWEVER!

It only properly reads english characters. I need the program to properly read korean characters too. I have tested and seen that the website properly sends korean characters when visiting in a browser. However my C# program just gets a bunch of garbage data if it is not english characters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try set `WebClient` encoding and send charset in your request.

`using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                    {
                        wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
                        HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
                    }`